# On completely additive state in von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It is unclear to me in a universal normal representation of von Neumann algebra $M$ say, how any completely additive state looks like vector state. I am reading the lemma 7.1.6 in Kadison Ringrose and I am not able to understand the proof. If anybody gives the universal normal representation idea of von Neumann algebra what it exactly means by giving example I will be really helpful to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you read before Lemma 7.1.6, near the bottom of page 458, the normal universal representation is defined to be the direct sum of the GNS representations of the additive states.

That is, $\Phi_n=\bigoplus_\eta \pi_\eta$ where $\eta$ runs over the completely additive states, and $\pi_\eta$ is the GNS representation. Explicitly,
$$
\omega(a)=\langle \pi_\omega (a) \Omega_\omega,\Omega_\omega\rangle=\langle \Phi_n(a)x,x\rangle,
$$
where $x=(x_\eta)$ is given by $x_\omega=\Omega_\omega$ and $x_\eta=0$ if $\eta\ne\omega$.

Comment: But can you please explain why in this universal representation any complete additive state look like vector state because the completely additive state needs to be faithful until support is full.

Comment: I have no idea what "needs to faithful until support is full" means. I have edited the answer to include more detail. All I did was write in symbols what it is said in the paragraph after 7.1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying the statement